# How can I enforce Basic Auth in Flask Restplus Swagger UI?

Tags: python, flask, basic-authentication, swagger-ui, flask-restplus

I am developing a back-end and using `Flask Restplus`. So far the code works great and the Swagger UI looks great too. I am considering adding Basic Auth on a particular endpoint (I am planning on using a Basic Auth Decorator from a previous `Flask-Restful` project).

How can I make the username and password fields visible on the swagger UI as well as actually enforce it on the UI? I was poking around the restplus documentation as well as Stack Overflow and didn't really see anything.

The UI will be visible on an intranet/LAN... I don't want this endpoint to be available to everyone in the building.

Comment: solved with the first example from this Github issue: https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/398

Answer (score 4):

Implement below:

```py
authorizations = {
    'Basic Auth': {
        'type': 'basic',
        'in': 'header',
        'name': 'Authorization'
    },
}

api = Namespace('User', description='user related operations',security='Bearer Auth', authorizations=authorizations)
```